What’s our status on translating questions?
A couple times recently on the main site, there have been questions on other languages.
The most recent one looked like it was written in Russian (I could easily be wrong), and I think the other was written maybe in Indonesian (can’t find it).
I’ve translated both of them to English using Google Translate, including an “this is probably inaccurate” disclaimer in both.
The edit went through on the first question (I’m pretty sure), but it was rejected for the second.
What’s our stance on translating these questions using a tool such as Google Translate and putting the translated edit below the original question, including a disclaimer so people know it probably wont be a 100% accurate?

I've closed this as a duplicate of the linked question. But our stance is no, this isn't a valid edit and not allowed. I think most SE sites follow this too. I know stackoverflow has a dedicated close reason for it even.

I can view the suggested edit review history, but I can't seem to find the suggested edit that you mentioned was approved. Do you remember any more details about the question? Like its title, and what game it was talking about?

That’s not Russian, it’s Ukrainian. The Russian alphabet doesn‘t have the “і” character that is in Ukrainian.
